# Cant setState in componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, geolocation

I am trying to set location in componentDidMount.  I am guessing `this` is not being passed in to the internal function.

See my example:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import GoogleMapReact from 'google-map-react';

const map = {
  width: '100%',
  height: '100vh'
};

const AnyReactComponent = ({ text }) => <div>{ text }</div>;

export default class Map extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      center: { lat: 40.7446790, lng: -73.9485420 },
      zoom: 11
    }
  };

  componentDidMount(){
    
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        function(position) {
          console.log(position);

          this.setState({
            center: { lat: position.coords.latitude, lng: position.coords.longitude },
          })              
        }
      )
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='map' style={ map }>
        <GoogleMapReact
          bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: 'AIzaSyD3Gu9y1qJChfayVFglovKEY2xjgKBiCJA' }}
          defaultCenter={ this.state.center }
          defaultZoom={ this.state.zoom }>
          <AnyReactComponent
            lat={ 40.7473310 }
            lng={ -73.8517440 }
            text={ "Where's Waldo?" }
          />
        </GoogleMapReact>
      </div>
    )
  };
};
```

This keeps happening and I have no idea why.

Can you help?

Comment: is it even getting into the if statement?

Answer (score 1):

First of all it is advised not to use setState in componentDidMount. Consider using componentWillMount.

Secondly you're using `this` inside a function. `this` does not refer to the component anymore. You might need to do infamous this->that conversion.

```
componentWillMount(){

const that = this;

if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    function(position) {
      console.log(position);

      that.setState({
        center: { lat: position.coords.latitude, lng: position.coords.longitude },
      })              
    }
  )
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You are usually not supposed to change the state in componentDidMount().

Read the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) for more information

Comment: Switched to componentWillMount.  Still getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of null
    at Map.js:26`

Comment: Not sure why this is down-voted. It is advised not to use setState in componentDidMount. You should use componentWillMount. But if you do need to use it you might need to disable your 'no-did-mount-set-state' rule if set. But it might put your component into a buggy state

Answer (score 0):

Change `function (position) {}` to an ES6 arrow function `(position) => {}` to preserve `this` in the closure

```
componentDidMount(){

if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    (position) => {
      console.log(position);

      this.setState({
        center: { lat: position.coords.latitude, lng: position.coords.longitude },
      })              
    }
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This composentDidMount should be better. Arrow function does not have "this". So "this" will refer to the component.

```
componentDidMount(){

if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    (position) => {
      console.log(position);

      this.setState({
        center: { lat: position.coords.latitude, lng: position.coords.longitude },
      })              
    }
  )
}
}
```